# Securing APIs called by angular app

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

There is a front end application written in Anuglar and there is no login form. But there is need to secure some of the apis that angular app calls.

Because this application is accessible to the world and no user's information is maintained to authenticate.

How we can make APIs secure to be called directly by any jmeter / curl command?

Comment: You are asking a question about your api but you put angularjs tag? What framework did you use for your api?

Comment: We are using spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure authentication on web server level, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for example Apache configuration (it includes JMeter side of things as well)